Check whether a commit is a stash entry
I need to know in my script whether a given commit is a standard commit or a stash entry.
The method should work also for dropped stashes that are not garbage collected yet, so it cannot rely on checking sha of existing stash entries (like git rev-parse stash@{X}).

Stash entries are regular commits. You can inspect them with git cat-file -p stash@{<number>}, they're merge commits between 1) the commit your HEAD pointed to when you stashed and 2) some commit automatically created by git when you stashed, referencing the state of the index at the moment you stashed.

This looks like an XY problem. What exactly are you trying to accomplish that makes you think you need to do this? Checking for dropped but not garbage-collected stashes seems like it would be a dirty operation anyway.

Do yourself and everyone else a favour and stop using stash and instead just check in temporary stuff as temporary commits.

@MarcoBonelli I'm writting a custom command for stash and before it makes any changes, I want it to verify if ref / sha provided by a user is indeed a stash. Is there any actual indication of an XY problem in the question? I feel that lately poeple here call XY problem every time they see something they didn't need themself earlier.

@hlovdal No. Stash is much too useful and convinient to ignore its existence.

@PiotrSiupa What does the stash do which couldn't be achieved with temporary commits?

@RomainValeri I can save my index, changes in my tracked files and all the untracked files with one simple command, and then restore them with one simple command.

@PiotrSiupa None of this is exclusive to git stash, it can be achieved with trivial aliases. But sorry for the off-topic sidenote, and of course everyone has preferences about how to work. Take care!

Stash have dangerous, complicated quirks that normal commits do not have.

@hlovdal 1) This is a skill issue not a quirk. Stash works like it should and it's intuitive. If you assume the numbers won't change when you delete entries, that's on you. You can always refer to stash entries by names if you're not sure. 2) That's not even a real problem. Simple git reset --hard undoes it. 3) Not a quirk, just inconvenient and if you want keep index and unstaged changes separate, using rebase is still harder. If you have this problem, you don't use stash the way it was intended. I have trouble imagining a situation when you would need to modify an existing stash entry.

@PiotrSiupa The sheer number of questions from people having screwed up with the stash is an argument in and of itself...

@RomainValeri I've run a search [git] stash is:question and it doesn't look like there is many of them at all. However, if you suggest that stash being popular is a reason to get rid of it, maybe we should also stop using rebase too because it seems to be much more questions it than about stash?

@PiotrSiupa From personal experience I have very often helped coworkers with stash mishandling, but then again, I don't advocate in favor of "never using stash", do as you wish.

A stash commit has 2 parents. Say parent1 and parent2. parent1 is also the only parent of parent2. The graph is like this,
*   9129d71 WIP on master: d2b25fd hello world
|\
| * f38c1f8 index on master: d2b25fd hello world
|/
* d2b25fd hello world

Update:
As @jthill points out, with git stash -u which also stashes untracked files, the head has a 3rd parent, parent3. parent3 is a root commit.
*-.   5ec4337 WIP on (no branch): d2b25fd hello world
|\ \
| | * b4b28c3 untracked files on (no branch): d2b25fd hello world
| * ca727e1 index on (no branch): d2b25fd hello world
|/
* d2b25fd hello world

The commit messages of them match certain patterns. The message of the stash entry starts with either WIP on $branch: (by git stash) or On $branch: (by git stash push -m $msg), followed by the short sha1sum and the subject of parent1. The message of parent2 startswith index on $branch:, followed by the short sha1sum and the subject of parent1. The message of parent3 also matches a pattern untracked files on $branch. On a detached HEAD, $branch is literal (no branch).
We can forge 3 or 4 commits with the same graph and messages on a normal branch, and the head can also be consumed by git stash apply $commit. But it's not common in real logs. So, if the 3 or 4 commits match the graph and their commit messages match these patterns, the head can be considered as a stash entry.

There can be three parents with -u aka --untracked, and the main stash's message is customizable, but yeah. That's about as good is you can get, whether it's usable as a stash is the only thing that matters, everything else is the XY problem mentioned.

It more or less what my own observations say. :-( I was hoping for some trick with reflog or something. I think I can rely on the tree structure but the messages. idk... that seems porcelain to me. Maybe I'll only issue a warning if they don't match.

@PiotrSiupa I think the index on: ref shorthash message at the second parent where the shorthash is the first parent should be reliable enough.
